# Why is modulus handle differently int and enum?

Tags: c, enums, modulo, ansi-c

If you run the following code, you'll see that modulus result can be negative on an integer, but is always positive on an enum.

It's ok for my case (I use it to cycle through a menu list of options), but I'd like to be sure that it is an ANSI constraint, and not a compiler implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum targets {
    TARGET1,
    TARGET2,
    TARGET3,
    TARGET4,
    NUMTARGETS,
};

int main() {
    int i;
    enum targets selected_enum = TARGET3;
    int selected_int = TARGET3;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        selected_enum = (selected_enum - 1) % NUMTARGETS;
        printf("Selected_enum = %d\n", selected_enum); /* I only see positive values */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        selected_int = (selected_int - 1) % NUMTARGETS;
        printf("Selected_int = %d\n", selected_int); /* I see negative values */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int` is signed, it's up to the implementation (compiler) if enumerations are signed or unsigned. In your case they seems to be unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to write

```
selected_enum = ( enum targets )( ( selected_enum - 1 ) % NUMTARGETS );
```

instead of

```
selected_enum = ( selected_enum - 1 ) % NUMTARGETS;
```

As for the result you got then it is implementation defined.

According to the C Standard (6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers)

> 4 Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer
>   type, or an unsigned integer type. **The choice of type is
>   implementation-defined**,128) but shall be capable of representing the
>   values of all the members of the enumeration. The enumerated type is
>   incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list of
>   enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter.

And (6.3 Conversions, 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> — The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the
>   **compatible integer type**

For example MS VC++ 2010 outputs

```
Selected_enum = 1
Selected_enum = 0
Selected_enum = -1
Selected_enum = -2
Selected_enum = -3
Selected_enum = 0
Selected_enum = -1
Selected_enum = -2
Selected_enum = -3
Selected_enum = 0
Selected_int = 1
Selected_int = 0
Selected_int = -1
Selected_int = -2
Selected_int = -3
Selected_int = 0
Selected_int = -1
Selected_int = -2
Selected_int = -3
Selected_int = 0
```

So it seems that the compiler you are using defines the enumeration compatible type as an unsigned type.

Try to run the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum targets { TARGET1, TARGET2, TARGET3, TARGET4, NUMTARGETS, };

    int i;
    enum targets selected_enum = TARGET3;
    int selected_int = TARGET3;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( ( selected_enum = ( enum targets )( selected_enum - 1 ) ) >= 0 ) printf( "unsigned %u\n", +selected_enum );
        else  printf( "signed %d\n", selected_enum );
    }


    return 0;
}
```

After running this program at www.ideone.com I got

```
unsigned 1
unsigned 0
unsigned 4294967295
unsigned 4294967294
unsigned 4294967293
unsigned 4294967292
unsigned 4294967291
unsigned 4294967290
unsigned 4294967289
unsigned 4294967288
```

while MS VC++ 2010 (and the on-line MS VC++ 2014 compiler) outputs

```
unsigned 1
unsigned 0
signed -1
signed -2
signed -3
signed -4
signed -5
signed -6
signed -7
signed -8
```

Answer (score 0):

Here targets is a user defined data type that will have the range between 0 and 4. So when the
value of the targets data type going under the zero it will come from the four. This is the reason that will not give the negative value.

In integer it is a (two/four) bytes. So it allows that in negative. You can check this.

Assign a value above 127 for the char variable then print that using the %d.You will get the
reason for that.

```
char a=170; printf("%d\n",a);
```

For this you will get the output as -86.

Comment: thats not how enums are defined in c